# view history of commands typed in other terminals by the same user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris

### Heading

When I type history, the output seems to tie to the current terminal. How can I view history of commands typed in other terminals by the same user? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command will shows the total history of commands entered on the terminal,

```
cat ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: or try `history | less`

Comment: contents shown by cat ~/.bash_history is not the same as history command:
$  cat ~/.bash_history|grep motif
$  history |grep motif
  559  rw -motif -f $DYNAMIC_DIR/riskwatch/sessionfiles/JS120008-rw.base-run000.scf